# Weighted percentile using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, weighted, percentile

Is there a way to use the numpy.percentile function to compute weighted percentile? Or is anyone aware of an alternative python function to compute weighted percentile?

thanks!

Comment: IMO [the solution by Sam A below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63440143/1156245) looks like a contender for current best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, numpy doesn't have built-in weighted functions for everything, but, you can always put something together.

```
def weight_array(ar, weights):
     zipped = zip(ar, weights)
     weighted = []
     for a, w in zipped:
         for j in range(w):
             weighted.append(a)
     return weighted


np.percentile(weight_array(ar, weights), 25)
```

Comment: To add to this solution, you might try just `np.percentile(Counter(dict(zip(ar, weights)).elements()), 25)`.  You'd need to `from collections import Counter`, and it doesn't do well with repeated keys in `ar`, but `Counter().elements()` is neat!

Comment: you are supposing weights to be integers

Comment: Also, it will likely use a lot of excess memory and CPU time for storing and sorting, respectively. Not suited for huge amount of data.

Answer (score 80):

### Completely vectorized numpy solution

Here is the code I use. It's not an optimal one (which I'm unable to write with `numpy`), but still much faster and more reliable than accepted solution

```py
def weighted_quantile(values, quantiles, sample_weight=None, 
                      values_sorted=False, old_style=False):
    """ Very close to numpy.percentile, but supports weights.
    NOTE: quantiles should be in [0, 1]!
    :param values: numpy.array with data
    :param quantiles: array-like with many quantiles needed
    :param sample_weight: array-like of the same length as `array`
    :param values_sorted: bool, if True, then will avoid sorting of
        initial array
    :param old_style: if True, will correct output to be consistent
        with numpy.percentile.
    :return: numpy.array with computed quantiles.
    """
    values = np.array(values)
    quantiles = np.array(quantiles)
    if sample_weight is None:
        sample_weight = np.ones(len(values))
    sample_weight = np.array(sample_weight)
    assert np.all(quantiles >= 0) and np.all(quantiles <= 1), \
        'quantiles should be in [0, 1]'

    if not values_sorted:
        sorter = np.argsort(values)
        values = values[sorter]
        sample_weight = sample_weight[sorter]

    weighted_quantiles = np.cumsum(sample_weight) - 0.5 * sample_weight
    if old_style:
        # To be convenient with numpy.percentile
        weighted_quantiles -= weighted_quantiles[0]
        weighted_quantiles /= weighted_quantiles[-1]
    else:
        weighted_quantiles /= np.sum(sample_weight)
    return np.interp(quantiles, weighted_quantiles, values)
```

Examples:

> weighted_quantile([1, 2, 9, 3.2, 4], [0.0, 0.5, 1.])

array([ 1. ,  3.2,  9. ])

> weighted_quantile([1, 2, 9, 3.2, 4], [0.0, 0.5, 1.], sample_weight=[2, 1, 2, 4, 1])

array([ 1. ,  3.2,  9. ])

Comment: Nice code. What's the difference for old_style? I haven't got the point yet.

Comment: @SubStruct : there is some minor difference in defining quantile. I.e. you have three elements. I would expect it's 0.5 quantile to be median (which is true in both cases) and 0.33 quantile to be mean of first two elements. For `old_style` (`numpy.percentile` way) this is not true. 

Difference in practice is minor.

Comment: Thank you.  I noticed that the difference is indeed minor for large sample.  However I don't understand why  we would expect the 0.33 quantile is 0.25 for array [0, 0.5, 1].

Comment: For me it seems 0.33 quantile is 0.33 for array [0, 0.5, 1] is more natural. Or it's a problem of definition, we just choose one according to the question we meet? Of course, it's not problem in most case.

Comment: @SubStruct my intuition is following: 0.33 should correspond to point where 1/3 of elements are smaller, 2/3 are greater. Taking point 'right in the middle' seems to be good solution, while actually I could use any point between first two elements.

Comment: I have updated your code a bit for my needs. First, I think the way you have coded `values_sorted` is a bit counter-intuitive to me. I look at it like someone is asking me, "Do you want your values sorted?" To which I answer, "Yes", and they sort the values. So, I changed `values_sorted` to be `True` by default. Second, my data has NaN values. I have included another variable `remove_nan=True` to deal with them. So I have another if statement, and I use `numpy.isfinite()` to get rid of infinite values and corresponding weights. Thanks for the great code! I stole it, but opensource! ;-)

Comment: Nice implementation of the method introduced in the last section of the wiki's webpage about weighted percentile [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Definition_of_the_Weighted_Percentile_method).

Comment: Note: For integer weights, the result of this function will be different from the more naive (or "correct", depending on definition) method of "repeating each value k times, where k is the weight", because it interpolates between a single point (with weight k) instead of k points of identical height.  For example, if values=[1, 2] and sample_weight=[1, 3], the weighted median is 1.75, but the un-weighted median of [1, 2, 2, 2] would be 2.

Comment: @jick this isn't just for integer weights right? This occurs any time the median lies "between" two points, e.g. `weighted_quantile([1, 2], 0.5, [1, 30.5]` also returns 1.97, where it really should be 2. Is there a way to get this result?

Comment: In general I'm struggling to create a simple, viable test of this function. The one provided in the answer doesn't test that the weighting works, since the answer is identical to the unweighted median.

Comment: @MaxGhenis I think you're right - it's just that with integer weight it's easier to assume that (weight 3) represents (same value repeated 3 times), which tripped me. :)

Comment: Since it uses interpolation with weights, a `round(weighted_quantile(...))` should give you the correct desired output for integers, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Alleo There seems to be an issue with this. I can't include the full example in a comment, but here's a pastebin that shows a failing example. I ask it for the `1` quantile, which should give me the maximum value regardless of weighting, but instead it gives a bizarrely low result. https://pastebin.com/4dxBHWAM

Comment: Disregard, it was an issue with numpy overflowing the int32 it was defaulting to.

Answer (score 15):

Cleaner and simpler using this [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile#Definition_of_the_Weighted_Percentile_method) for weighted percentile method.

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_percentile(data, weights, perc):
    """
    perc : percentile in [0-1]!
    """
    ix = np.argsort(data)
    data = data[ix] # sort data
    weights = weights[ix] # sort weights
    cdf = (np.cumsum(weights) - 0.5 * weights) / np.sum(weights) # 'like' a CDF function
    return np.interp(perc, cdf, data)
```

Answer (score 15):

This seems to be now implemented in statsmodels

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW
wq = DescrStatsW(data=np.array([1, 2, 9, 3.2, 4]), weights=np.array([0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.3, 0.5]))
wq.quantile(probs=np.array([0.1, 0.9]), return_pandas=False)
# array([2., 9.])
```

The DescrStatsW object also has other methods implemented, such as weighted mean, etc. https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html

Answer (score 13):

A quick solution, by first sorting and then interpolating:

```
def weighted_percentile(data, percents, weights=None):
    ''' percents in units of 1%
        weights specifies the frequency (count) of data.
    '''
    if weights is None:
        return np.percentile(data, percents)
    ind=np.argsort(data)
    d=data[ind]
    w=weights[ind]
    p=1.*w.cumsum()/w.sum()*100
    y=np.interp(percents, p, d)
    return y
```

Comment: This produces different results for `weighted_percentile(np.array([0,3,6,9]),50,weights=np.array([1,3,3,1]))` and `weighted_percentile(np.array([0,3,3,3,6,6,6,9]),50,weights=None)`

Comment: Changing `1.*w.cumsum()` to `(1.*w.cumsum()-0.5*w)` (per [@imbr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61343915/66516) produces the expected result for the above.

Answer (score 10):

I don' know what's Weighted percentile means, but from @Joan Smith's answer, It seems that you just need to repeat every element in `ar`, you can use `numpy.repeat()`:

```
import numpy as np
np.repeat([1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

the result is:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: I suppose this is the better (as in more efficient) answer.

Comment: Still, this only supports integer weights. And will most likely be very memory and CPU-time heavy for a larger data set.

Comment: From personal experience I can confirm that this approach is definitely not efficient. If your vectors are long and the weights are big numbers your computer can quickly hit the memory limit.

Comment: Also that wouldn't work with non-integer weights.

Answer (score 10):

Apologies for the additional (unoriginal) answer (not enough rep to comment on @nayyarv's).  His solution worked for me (ie. it replicates the default behavior of `np.percentage`), but I think you can eliminate the for loop with clues from how the original `np.percentage` is written.

```
def weighted_percentile(a, q=np.array([75, 25]), w=None):
    """
    Calculates percentiles associated with a (possibly weighted) array

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array-like
        The input array from which to calculate percents
    q : array-like
        The percentiles to calculate (0.0 - 100.0)
    w : array-like, optional
        The weights to assign to values of a.  Equal weighting if None
        is specified

    Returns
    -------
    values : np.array
        The values associated with the specified percentiles.  
    """
    # Standardize and sort based on values in a
    q = np.array(q) / 100.0
    if w is None:
        w = np.ones(a.size)
    idx = np.argsort(a)
    a_sort = a[idx]
    w_sort = w[idx]

    # Get the cumulative sum of weights
    ecdf = np.cumsum(w_sort)

    # Find the percentile index positions associated with the percentiles
    p = q * (w.sum() - 1)

    # Find the bounding indices (both low and high)
    idx_low = np.searchsorted(ecdf, p, side='right')
    idx_high = np.searchsorted(ecdf, p + 1, side='right')
    idx_high[idx_high > ecdf.size - 1] = ecdf.size - 1

    # Calculate the weights 
    weights_high = p - np.floor(p)
    weights_low = 1.0 - weights_high

    # Extract the low/high indexes and multiply by the corresponding weights
    x1 = np.take(a_sort, idx_low) * weights_low
    x2 = np.take(a_sort, idx_high) * weights_high

    # Return the average
    return np.add(x1, x2)

# Sample data
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 3.2, 4.0], dtype=np.float)
w = np.array([2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0], dtype=np.float)

# Make an unweighted "copy" of a for testing
a2 = np.repeat(a, w.astype(np.int))

# Tests with different percentiles chosen
q1 = np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 11)
q2 = np.linspace(5.0, 95.0, 10)
q3 = np.linspace(4.0, 94.0, 10)
for q in (q1, q2, q3):
    assert np.all(weighted_percentile(a, q, w) == np.percentile(a2, q))
```

Comment: This is useful. However, I had to wrap `idx_high[idx_high > ecdf.size - 1] = ecdf.size - 1` in a conditional statement in order to make it work for single percentiles as well. Guess that's why there's the `zerod` in the numpy source code.

Answer (score 4):

The [`weightedcalcs` package](https://github.com/jsvine/weightedcalcs) supports [quantiles](https://github.com/jsvine/weightedcalcs/blob/master/weightedcalcs/core.py#L80):

```
import weightedcalcs as wc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [1, 2, 3], 'w': [3, 2, 1]})
calc = wc.Calculator('w')  # w designates weight

calc.quantile(df, 'v', 0.5)
# 1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in comments, simply repeating values is impossible for float weights, and impractical for very large datasets. There is a library that does weighted percentiles here: 
http://kochanski.org/gpk/code/speechresearch/gmisclib/gmisclib.weighted_percentile-module.html
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function for my needs:

```
def quantile_at_values(values, population, weights=None):
    values = numpy.atleast_1d(values).astype(float)
    population = numpy.atleast_1d(population).astype(float)
    # if no weights are given, use equal weights
    if weights is None:
        weights = numpy.ones(population.shape).astype(float)
        normal = float(len(weights))
    # else, check weights                  
    else:                                           
        weights = numpy.atleast_1d(weights).astype(float)
        assert len(weights) == len(population)
        assert (weights >= 0).all()
        normal = numpy.sum(weights)                    
        assert normal > 0.
    quantiles = numpy.array([numpy.sum(weights[population <= value]) for value in values]) / normal
    assert (quantiles >= 0).all() and (quantiles <= 1).all()
    return quantiles
```

- It is vectorized as far as I could go.
- It has a lot of sanity checks.
- It works with floats as weights.
- It can work without weights (→ equal weights).
- It can compute multiple quantiles at once.

Multiply results by 100 if you want percentiles instead of quantiles.

Comment: nb this returns the quantile at value as the function says, interesting and related but not answering the OP which asks about percentiles ( and no percentile != quantile * 100 )

Answer (score 2):

```python
def weighted_percentile(a, percentile = np.array([75, 25]), weights=None):
    """
    O(nlgn) implementation for weighted_percentile.
    """
    percentile = np.array(percentile)/100.0
    if weights is None:
        weights = np.ones(len(a))
    a_indsort = np.argsort(a)
    a_sort = a[a_indsort]
    weights_sort = weights[a_indsort]
    ecdf = np.cumsum(weights_sort)

    percentile_index_positions = percentile * (weights.sum()-1)+1
    # need the 1 offset at the end due to ecdf not starting at 0
    locations = np.searchsorted(ecdf, percentile_index_positions)

    out_percentiles = np.zeros(len(percentile_index_positions))

    for i, empiricalLocation in enumerate(locations):
        # iterate across the requested percentiles 
        if ecdf[empiricalLocation-1] == np.floor(percentile_index_positions[i]):
            # i.e. is the percentile in between 2 separate values
            uppWeight = percentile_index_positions[i] - ecdf[empiricalLocation-1]
            lowWeight = 1 - uppWeight

            out_percentiles[i] = a_sort[empiricalLocation-1] * lowWeight + \
                                 a_sort[empiricalLocation] * uppWeight
        else:
            # i.e. the percentile is entirely in one bin
            out_percentiles[i] = a_sort[empiricalLocation]

    return out_percentiles
```

This is my function, it give identical behaviour to

```
np.percentile(np.repeat(a, weights), percentile)
```

With less memory overhead. np.percentile is an O(n) implementation so it's potentially faster for small weights.
It has all the edge cases sorted out - it's an exact solution. The interpolation answers above assume linear, when it's a step for most of the case, except when the weight is 1.

Say we have data [1,2,3] with weights [3, 11, 7] and I want the 25%  percentile. My ecdf is going to be [3, 10, 21] and I'm looking for the 5th value. The interpolation will see [3,1] and [10, 2] as the matches and interpolate giving 1.28 despite being entirely in the 2nd bin with a value of 2.

Comment: This is plain wrong!

Answer (score -1):

here my solution:

```
def my_weighted_perc(data,perc,weights=None):
    if weights==None:
        return nanpercentile(data,perc)
    else:
        d=data[(~np.isnan(data))&(~np.isnan(weights))]
        ix=np.argsort(d)
        d=d[ix]
        wei=weights[ix]
        wei_cum=100.*cumsum(wei*1./sum(wei))
        return interp(perc,wei_cum,d)
```

it simply calculates the weighted CDF of the data and then it uses to estimate the weighted percentiles.