# Weighted version of scipy percentileofscore

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'd like to pass weights to [`scipy.stats.percentileofscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html). For example:

```
from scipy import stats
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
val = 3
stats.percentileofscore(a, val)
```

Returns 75, as 75% of the values in `a` lie at or below the `val` 3.

I'd like to add weights, for example:

```
weights = [2, 2, 3, 3]
weightedpercentileofscore(a, val, weights)
```

Should return 70, since (2 + 2 + 3) / (2 + 2 + 3 + 3) = 7 / 10 of the weights fall at or below 3.

This should also work for decimal weights and large weights, so just expanding the arrays isn't ideal.

[Weighted percentile using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844024/weighted-percentile-using-numpy) is relevant, but calculates percentiles (e.g. asking for the 10th percentile value) rather than the specific percentile for a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_percentile_of_score(a, weights, score, kind='weak'):
    npa = np.array(a)
    npw = np.array(weights)

    if kind == 'rank':  # Equivalent to 'weak' since we have weights.
        kind = 'weak'

    if kind in ['strict', 'mean']:
        indx = npa < score
        strict = 100 * sum(npw[indx]) / sum(weights)
    if kind == 'strict':
        return strict

    if kind in ['weak', 'mean']:    
        indx = npa <= score
        weak = 100 * sum(npw[indx]) / sum(weights)
    if kind == 'weak':
        return weak

    if kind == 'mean':
        return (strict + weak) / 2


a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
weights = [2, 2, 3, 3]
print(weighted_percentile_of_score(a, weights, 3))  # 70.0 as desired.
```

In practice, what you want to do is see the overall weight of the scores less or equal than your threshold score - divided by the whole sum of weights and in percent.

To get each value's corresponding weighted percentile as an array:

```
[weighted_percentile_of_score(a, weights, val) for val in a]
# [20.0, 40.0, 70.0, 100.0]
```