# Python weighted quantile as R wtd.quantile()

Tags: python, r, numpy, quantile, hmisc

I want to convert the `R` package `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()` into python.

Here is the example in R:
[image]

I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844024/weighted-percentile-using-numpy) as reference and it seems that the logics are different than R:

```
# First function
def weighted_quantile(values, quantiles, sample_weight = None,
                              values_sorted = False, old_style = False):
    """ Very close to numpy.percentile, but supports weights.
    NOTE: quantiles should be in [0, 1]!
    :param values: numpy.array with data
    :param quantiles: array-like with many quantiles needed
    :param sample_weight: array-like of the same length as `array`
    :return: numpy.array with computed quantiles.
    """
    values = np.array(values)
    quantiles = np.array(quantiles)
    if sample_weight is None:
        sample_weight = np.ones(len(values))
    sample_weight = np.array(sample_weight)
    assert np.all(quantiles >= 0) and np.all(quantiles <= 1),         'quantiles should be in [0, 1]'

    if not values_sorted:
        sorter = np.argsort(values)
        values = values[sorter]
        sample_weight = sample_weight[sorter]

    # weighted_quantiles = np.cumsum(sample_weight)
    # weighted_quantiles /= np.sum(sample_weight)
    weighted_quantiles = np.cumsum(sample_weight)/np.sum(sample_weight)
    return np.interp(quantiles, weighted_quantiles, values)

weighted_quantile(values = [0.4890342, 0.4079128, 0.5083345, 0.2136325, 0.6197319],
                  quantiles = np.arange(0, 1 + 1 / 5, 1 / 5),
                  sample_weight = [1,1,1,1,1])

>> array([0.2136325, 0.2136325, 0.4079128, 0.4890342, 0.5083345, 0.6197319])
```

```
# Second function
def weighted_percentile(data, weights, perc):
    """
    perc : percentile in [0-1]!
    """
    data = np.array(data)
    weights = np.array(weights)
    ix = np.argsort(data)
    data = data[ix] # sort data
    weights = weights[ix] # sort weights
    cdf = (np.cumsum(weights) - 0.5 * weights) / np.sum(weights) # 'like' a CDF function
    return np.interp(perc, cdf, data)

weighted_percentile([0.4890342, 0.4079128, 0.5083345, 0.2136325, 0.6197319], [1,1,1,1,1], np.arange(0, 1 + 1 / 5, 1 / 5))

>> array([0.2136325 , 0.31077265, 0.4484735 , 0.49868435, 0.5640332 ,
       0.6197319 ])
```

Both are different with R. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Python-illiterate, but from what I see and after some quick checks I can tell you the following.

Here you use uniform (sampling) weights, so you could also directly use the `quantile()` function. Not surprisingly, it gives the same results as `wtd.quantile()` with uniform weights:

```
x <- c(0.4890342, 0.4079128, 0.5083345, 0.2136325, 0.6197319)
n <- length(x)
x <- sort(x)
quantile(x, probs = seq(0,1,0.2))
#       0%       20%       40%       60%       80%      100% 
# 0.2136325 0.3690567 0.4565856 0.4967543 0.5306140 0.6197319
```

The R `quantile()` function get the quantiles in a 'textbook' way, i.e. by determining the index i of the obs to use with i = q(n+1).
In your case:

```
seq(0,1,0.2)*(n+1)
# 0.0 1.2 2.4 3.6 4.8 6.0
```

Of course since you have 5 values/obs and you want quintiles, the indices are not integers. But you know for example that the first quintile (i = 1.2) lies between obs 1 and obs 2. More precisely, it is a linear combination of the two observations (the 'weights' are derived from the value of the index):

```
0.2*x[1] + 0.8*x[2]
# 0.3690567
```

You can do the same for the all the quintiles, on the basis of the indices:

```
q <-
    c(min(x), ## 0: actually, the first obs
      0.2*x[1] + 0.8*x[2], ## 1.2: quintile lies between obs 1 and 2
      0.4*x[2] + 0.6*x[3], ## 2.4: quintile lies between obs 2 and 3
      0.6*x[3] + 0.4*x[4], ## 3.6: quintile lies between obs 3 and 4
      0.8*x[4] + 0.2*x[5], ## 4.8: quintile lies between obs 4 and 5
      max(x)  ## 6: actually, the last obs
      )
q
# 0.2136325 0.3690567 0.4565856 0.4967543 0.5306140 0.6197319
```

You can see that you get exactly the output of `quantile()` and `wtd.quantile()`.

If instead of `0.2*x[1] + 0.8*x[2]` we consider the following:

```
0.5*x[1] + 0.5*x[2]
# 0.3107726
```

We get the output of your second Python function. It appears that your second function considers uniform 'weights' (obviously I am not talking about the sampling weights here) when combining the two observations. The issue (at least for the second Python function) seems to come from this. I know these are just insights, but I hope they will help.

EDIT: note that the difference between the two is not necessary an 'issue' with the python code. There are different quantile estimators (and their weighted versions) and the python functions could simply rely on a different estimator than `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()`. I think that the latter uses the weighted version of the Harrell-Davis quantile estimator. If you really want to implement this one, you should check the source code of `Hmisc::wtd.quantile()` and try to 'directly' translate this  into Python.

Comment: If the `sample_weight` is not all `1`. What will this be?

Comment: @PeterChen likely that it will still differ, since it is likely that these functions rely on different estimators (cf my edit). Sorry not to dig more into that, I hope that the edit will at least point towards a fruitful direction for you.